# Polymer Dart - Can't access elements inside a template element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm having trouble accessing the elements that are within `<template if = "{{something}}">`. I've read some posts published on the web and mainly the solution involves the use of `MutationObserver`. The problem is i've template elements chained with other template elements. Below's an illustration:

```dart
       <template repeat="{{container in containers}}">
        <!-- Tab content -->
        <div id="{{container.secondname}}" class="{{container.secondname}}">
          <template id="firstTemplate" if="{{currentContainer.photos.isEmpty}}">
              (...)
          </template>
          <template id="secondTemplate-{{container.name}}" if="{{currentContainer.photos.isNotEmpty}}">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">     
                <section class="centerStuff">
                  <template if="{{container.photosToDisplay.length < 1}}">
                    (...)
                  </template>
                  <template if="{{container.photosToDisplay.length > 0}}">
                      <template if="{{isInOverflow}}">
                        <div on-click="{{moveLeft}}" id="thumb-back"></div>
                      </template>    
                      <ul id="nav-{{container.secondname}}" class="navlistHorizontal">
                        <template repeat="{{photo in currentContainer.photosToDisplay}}">  
                          <li> 
                            <div class="mementoSpecialImage">
                              <div class="imageBoard">
                                <img src="{{photo.miniThumbnailToShow.src}}"
                                     class="image img-thumbnail"
                                     title="{{photo.title}}"
                                     on-click="{{showImage}}"
                                     id="{{photo.title}}"
                                     data-id="{{photo.id}}" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

How can i proceed to access the `img`  element?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have tried something? What didn't work? Where did you put the code you used to access the element?

Comment: Yes @GünterZöchbauer. Using simply $[] doesn't work as expected. And MutationObserver not seem to be a proper solution to this situation because I have more than one repeat template. I was trying to descend the tree of elements but when i reach <template id="secondTemplate-{{container.name}}" if="{{currentContainer.photos.isNotEmpty}}"> there's no children. Still would not be a proper way to solve the problem in my view. 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That `$[]` doesn't work with elements inside `<template if/repeat>` is a know issue, I guess you found the `MutationObserver` workaround in the discussion about the issue. The `querySelector()` solution in my answer should work but only when the element is actually shown. When the element is inside an `<template if="{{false}}">` there is no way to select the element because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
var img = this.querySelector('.imageBoard .image img-thumbnail') as ImageElement;
```

Comment: By assigning a specific CSS class or id to the element. Only those elements are returned where the selector matches.